# Print the value of a Point to the terminal

Tags: java, static, points

I created a class that can find the distance between two points and the value of the midpoint between them:

```
public class Point {

    private double x;
    private double y;

    public Point (double x, double y) {

        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public double getX() {
        return x;
    }

    public void setX(double x) {
        this.x = x;
    }

    public double getY() {
        return y;
    }

    public void setY(double y) {
        this.y = y;
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Point p1 = new Point(1,1);
        Point p2 = new Point(4,5);
        System.out.println("The distance between p1 and p2 is: " + distance(p1, p2));
        System.out.println("The midpoint of p1 and p2 is: " + findMidpoint(p1, p2));
    }

    public static double distance(Point p1, Point p2) {
         return Math.sqrt((p1.getX() - p2.getX()) *  (p1.getX() - p2.getX()) + 
                          (p1.getY() - p2.getY()) *  (p1.getY() - p2.getY()));
    }

    public static Point findMidpoint (Point p1, Point p2) {
        return new Point((p1.getX() + p2.getX()) / 2, (p1.getY() + p2.getY()) / 2);
    }
}
```

This code compiles fine but when I run it, it gives the output:

```
The distance between p1 and p2 is: 5.0
The midpoint of p1 and p2 is: Point@15db9742
```

It gives the same value for the midpoint regardless of the values of p1 and p2. I want to output the midpoint in the format "**(x,y)**".

Could somebody also explain why I was forced to make the distance and findMidpoint methods static?

Comment: overide `toString()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Why do I get the same output each time?**

Because you're not overriding the `toString` method.  The value you're seeing is java's implementation of `toString`.  Every object has this behavior.

Put this method in your point class to override java's `toString` implementation.

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return "("+x+", "+y+")";
}
```

This will give you output in the format `(x, y)` as you requested.

**Why are midpoint and distance static?**

The methods being static was a design decision.  They could be written to be non-static, but it would make less sense as the methods don't change the state of either point object involved.

Comment: `This will give you output in the format (x, y)` ... not really :P. You're missing the comma.

Comment: Also missing the plus sign between y and ")" XD

Comment: I must start using an online syntax checker. Thanks @Shiftz I've corrected.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a `toString()` method:

```
public String toString() {
    return String.format("Point(%f,%f)",x,y);
}
```

Then you get:

```
java Point
The distance between p1 and p2 is: 5.0
The midpoint of p1 and p2 is: Point(2.500000,3.000000)
```

Answer (score 1):

`Point@15db9742` is the "default" output behavior of [`Object#toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString%28%29). If you want to change that, then override this method:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Point[" +
      "x=" + x +
      ", y=" + y +
      "]";
}
```

That should print:

```
Point[x=100.0, y=100.0]
```

instead.